# Environment Variables setting with value of a Windows Environment Variable

Tags: environment-variables, putty

I´m need to set a Variable on Linux using the configration on Putty. I can do that by setting this Variable on SSHD.CONF. It works.

But, I need to set this value dinamically, first I set the variable on Windows:

```
set WIN_USER_CODE=1324567890
```

Then I m trying to configure this as a value on PuTTy:

Category > Connection > Data > Environment Variables
  Variable : LC_USER_CODE  (authorized on sshd.conf)
  Value    : WIN_USER_CODE (value of the variable setted on Windows)

I doesn´t work... I´d tried in different ways like %WIN_USER_CODE%, $WIN_USER_CODE...

Can anybody help me with that?

Thanks!

Comment: I find a way to solve this, I simply generated a .reg file with the address of the key, and setted the value using the command:
regedit /s arquivo.reg
Then, I fynally call the putty session.